# "No space left on device" when using dd to create a disk image

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, backup, dd

I am trying to trying to create a disk image of my Raspberry Pi Model 3 B+ onto a USB drive using dd. I know there are easier ways to do this on a Raspberry Pi, but I want to try this to test the procedure on a 'sacrificial' system, which I hope to then use on another linux computer running a much larger Ubuntu disk to create a backup. OS is Raspbian Buster 10.

I have been following a procedure I found on an article here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-clone-restore-linux-disk-image-dd/

The USB drive has 64GB capacity and has been formatted, initially as exFAT but I also tried NTFS thinking maybe that was the issue. The command ended with the same error, however each time i have tried this the file size transferred has been different, varying from 2-8GB in size before the error occurred.

This is to identify my drives - the SD card is "mmcblk" and my USB drive is "sda", called "NINJA":

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1 57.9G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    1 57.9G  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0 14.9G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 14.6G  0 part /
```

This my command I tried to use:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/media/pi/NINJA/raspibackup.img
```

and this is the output:

```
dd: error writing '/media/pi/NINJA/raspibackup.img': No space left on device
605+0 records in
604+0 records out
2535124992 bytes (2.5 GB, 2.4 GiB) copied, 325.617 s, 7.8 MB/s
```

Comment: Just a sidenote, I encountered the same problem today when using the new status=progress option on DD. I guess, it somehow caches the data then. Without the status=progess option, it worked fine.

Comment: I'm getting this error in ubuntu when using the command: sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4k && sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check how much disk space is "Avail" on the target device.

Example:

```
[jack@server1 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 484M     0  484M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    496M   41M  456M   9% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    496M  6.9M  489M   2% /run
tmpfs                    496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root  6.2G  6.2G  172K 100% /
/dev/sda1               1014M  166M  849M  17% /boot
tmpfs                    100M   24K  100M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0                 552M  552M     0 100% /run/media/jack/CentOS 7 x86_64
```

Terminology:

- df: DiskFree
- -h:  Human Readable Sizes (Ex: 6.2G instead of 6485900)

In this example, let's say I want to make a backup of the Boot drive (/dev/sda1) and save it in my Local User Home Folder on my Root Drive (/dev/mapper/centos-root).

When I so this, I will get an error that looks like:

```
[jack@server1 ~]$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=boot.img
dd: error writing 'boot.img': No space left on device
1736905+0 records in
1736904+0 records out
889294848 bytes (889 MB) copied, 4.76575 s, 187 MB/s
```

Terminology:

- sudo: Super User Do
- dd:   Disk Duplicate
- if:   Input File (source)
- of:   Output File (destination)

The system is trying to copy ALL of /dev/sda1 (to include freespace) to boot.img, which is impossible at this because /dev/sda1 is 1014M and there is only 172K space left on /dev/mapper/centos-root.

With that said, the actual size of the /dev/sda is actually 16G total!  Which means that there is 8G not allocated.

My /dev/sda1 should be 1G where my /dev/sda2 (centos-root) should be 15G... in which it is currently 6.2G

```
[jack@server1 ~]$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   16G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0   15G  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0  6.2G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0  820M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0              11:0    1  552M  0 rom  /run/media/jack/CentOS 7 x86_64
```

This partition can be extended by doing the following:

```
[jack@server1 ~]$ sudo lvextend -L +8G /dev/mapper/centos-root
[jack@server1 ~]$ sudo xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/centos-root
```

Now that my partition is extended, I can do another DiskFree command to double check.

```
[jack@server1 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 484M     0  484M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    496M   33M  463M   7% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    496M  6.9M  489M   2% /run
tmpfs                    496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root   15G  7.0G  7.3G  49% /
/dev/sda1               1014M  166M  849M  17% /boot
tmpfs                    100M   24K  100M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0                 552M  552M     0 100% /run/media/jack/CentOS 7 x86_64
```

My root partition is now 15G!  Now I can perform my backup of the /dev/sda1 partition!

```
[jack@server1 ~]$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=boot.img
2097152+0 records in
2097152+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 5.59741 s, 192 MB/s
```

Mission Complete!

Comment: Thanks Stryker2k2 this makes sense to me now

Comment: My pleasure! Let me know if you run into anymore dd issues :) Thank you for selecting this as the answer and I hope this answer helps out others with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

`sda1` is not mounted in `/media/pi/NINJA/`, the image you create is therefore stored on the `mmcblk0p2` partition.

Since `mmcblk0` is by definition larger than `mmcblk0p2`, you logically run out of space on it.

## Solution :

You need to first mount `sda1` using `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/pi/NINJA/` and try your dd command again after.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.

Comment: @jww apologies if my question is off-topic, can you help me understand why? I am a very new user and want to improve my understanding how to post in this forum.